# Run VBA on record change and not form open Access 2013

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I have two criteria for my macro.

- It should run only when the user switches records
- It should run whether or not the record was modified

`On Current` works but it also runs on form open. `After Update` only runs if a field is changed. Is there an event that fulfils my criteria?

Comment: When you say macro, do you mean a VBA procedure or an Access macro object?  Excel users often call VBA procedures macros, but an Access macro is something different.

Comment: A third criteria: How do I cancel switching to another record? I use `Cancel = True` and `Me.Undo` to revert the data but it still switches to the other record.

Comment: @HansUp It's the type that can be edited via the form's Design View or by opening the editor with Alt + F11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a *static* variable:

```
Private Sub Form_Current()

    Static Opened As Boolean

    If Opened = False
        ' Form opens.
        Opened = True
    Else
        ' Do stuff.
    End If

End Sub
```

To manipulate the previous record:

```
Private Sub Form_Current()

    Static Opened As Boolean
    Static LastId As Long

    If Opened = False
        ' Form opens.
        Opened = True
    ElseIf LastId <> 0 Then
        ' Do stuff using LastId as the Id.            
    End If

    ' Save current Id.
    LastId = Nz(Me!Id.Value, 0)

End Sub
```

Comment: That's clever, I would have never thought to try that. Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps you could help me with an issue that popped up. The `On Current` event runs the macro for the newly selected record, not the record that the user is finishing up with. Is there another event for this?

Comment: You could use another static to hold the Id of the last visited record. See edit.